# Command Line Arguments not getting executed in C

Tags: c, terminal, exec, fork

I am trying to pass arguments to execl() function for ls command. But when I pass

```
/bin/ls -l -a
```

as arguments to my program, the execl() function doesn't recognise the last two arguments. Why is that?Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i,childpid;

if(argc!=4)
{
    printf("you didn't provide any commandline arguments!\n");
    return 0;
}

childpid=fork();

if(childpid<0)
{
    printf("fork() failed\n");
    return 0;
}
else
    if(childpid==0)
    {
         printf("My ID %d\n\n",getpid());
        execl(argv[1],argv[2], argv[3],NULL);

        printf("If you can see this message be ware that Exec() failed!\n");
    }

    while(wait(NULL)>0);

    printf("My ID %d, Parent ID %d, CHild ID %d\n", getpid(),getppid(),childpid);

    return 0;
}
```

I am on Ubuntu.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running your program `/bin/ls` appears to ignore the `-l` argument because it is passed in the position reserved for `argv[0]`, which is normally the (rather useless) program name.

Specifically, the first argument to `execl` is the program to run, and the remaining arguments get copied to `argv` vector as-is. Since `argv[0]` is expected to contain the program name and the actual arguments begin from `argv[1]`, you must compensate by providing the program name twice:

```
execl(argv[1], argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], (char *) NULL);
```

Comment: I did cast null to char* but still the result obtained by executing ls -a -l in terminal and passing them to program and running through execl are different

Comment: @Alfred I don't think the missing cast was ever the real problem; not repeating `argv[1]` was. This is explained in the answer and this is what differs my answer from that of Desert Ice and hmjd.

Answer (score 1):

One mistake in the code is the use of `NULL` as the last argument to `execl()`. From [man execl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl):

> The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(), and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn. Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the executed program. The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed. **The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.**

See the question [How do I get a null pointer in my programs?](http://c-faq.com/null/null2.html) from the C FAQ, which specifically mentions `excel()` in its example.

Comment: +1 very interesting, but what is the difference between passing a pointer and an `int` on the stack ?

Comment: I did cast null to char* but still the result obtained by executing ls -a -l in terminal and passing them to program and running through execl are different

Answer (score 0):

The code does not work for me until I add `#include<unistd.h>`

As far as i know the functions exec,execl etc are declared in unistd.h and not in stdlib.h.

I do get warnings if i compile only with stdlib.h and stdio.h.

`test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:24:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘execl’ [enabled by default]`

There if you add unistd.h, and change the exec call to

`execl(argv[1], argv[1], argv[2], argv[3],NULL);`

your program should work.