# Create child using fork() inside for loop to run execlp()

Tags: c, linux, for-loop, exec, fork

I am writing a C program which will run Linux commands, like:

> $ cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d: | sort

The idea is to create child process using fork() to run the commands using execlp(). I planned to use two pipes for the communication and direct the input-output using dup().

The output is wrong:

> ls -l | wc -c on command returns 1746
>   the program returns 1761

The code(edited to reflect suggestions):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
  int i,fd1[2],status,listpid[2];
  pid_t child;
  pipe(fd1);

  for(i=0; i< 2; i++)
  {
    printf("\ncreating child\n");
    if((child = fork()) == -1)
    {
      perror("fork");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    else if(child == 0)
    {
      if(i == 0)
      {
    close(1); dup(fd1[1]);
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd1[1]);
    printf("\nrunning ls -l\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    execlp("ls","ls","-l", (char *)NULL);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

      }
      else if(i == 1)
      {
    close(0); dup(fd1[0]);
    close(fd1[1]);
    close(fd1[0]);
    printf("\nrunning wc -c\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    execlp("wc","wc","-c", (char *)NULL);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

      }

    }
    else
    {
      listpid[i]=child;
    }

  }

  close(fd1[0]);
  close(fd1[1]);

  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
  {
    waitpid(listpid[i], &status, 0);

    if(WIFEXITED(status)) 
    {
      printf("\n[%d] TERMINATED (Status: %d)\n",listpid[i], WEXITSTATUS(status));

    }

  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438643/command-line-arguments-not-getting-executed-in-c/13438677#13438677 for use of `NULL` as last argument.

Comment: It's traditional to put the `\n` at the end of your `printf`, this also avoids having to flush `stdout` if it's a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your update, the two child processes are behaving correctly.  However, you still need to add:

```
close(fd1[0]);
close(fd1[1]);
```

between the `for` loop that launches the children and the `for` loop that collects the exit statuses.

Because the write end of the pipe is still open, `wc` does not receive EOF, so it doesn't terminate, so your process is waiting indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the hanging problem. But the output is still wrong.

Comment: What's wrong about the output?  Did you remember that standard output is send down the pipe, so your diagnostic printing is sent to `wc -c`, inflating the character count compared with what you get by running `ls -l | wc -c` in the shell?  There's a reason why `stderr` exists; it is so that diagnostic information is not sent down pipes to cause confusion.  If you change `printf(` into `fprintf(stderr,` globally, then the count from your program agrees with what the shell gets from `ls -l | wc -c`.

Answer (score 1):

First you can't waitpid in the loop -- if the output of ls is big enough it ill fill the pipe, and so it won't finish until someone reads it: you must wait for both children after the for loop.
Second -- the wc will go on for as long as the other end of the pipe is open, ie you will have to close the pipe in the parent as well.

Comment: like this?                                             
    if((child == 0)
    { 
           
    }
    else
    {
      if (i == 0)
      {
 close(fd1[1]);
      }
      else if(i%2 != 0)
      {
 close(fd1[0]);
      }
      
    }

Comment: @user1863673: generally, if you `dup()` or `dup2()` one descriptor of a pair returned by `pipe()`, you need to close _both_ the descriptors returned by `pipe()`.  There probably are exceptions; they are few and far between.

Comment: still does not fix the problem.